# Creating a matrix of permutations

Tags: python, permutation

I'm trying to make a matrix of permutations that I can evaluate the subsets of, but I'm having trouble actually making the matrix.

The goal is to take 4 unique numbers (lets say 4 5 6 7) and find all the permutations(4x3x2x1 = 24) and evaluate their subsets. E.g. one number would be "6475" and the first subset is the first two digits would be "64" and the second subset is the last two digits "75"

However I cannot my list of permutations to be cleaned up so I can evaluate each element individually.

Here is my code:

```
int_matrix = []

matrix = list(permutations([1,2,3,4]))
int_matrix = [int(i) for i in matrix.split(",")]
```

And I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

The output for my permutations is :

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 3), (1, 3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4, 2), (1, 4, 2, 3), (1, 4, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3, 4).....
```

I think my problem is I'm not removing the commas from "matrix" correctly. Any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to convert your tuples to int :

```
>>> [reduce(lambda x,y :x*10+y,i) for i in matrix]
[1234, 1243, 1324, 1342, 1423, 1432, 2134, 2143, 2314, 2341, 2413, 2431, 3124, 3142, 3214, 3241, 3412, 3421, 4123, 4132, 4213, 4231, 4312, 4321]
```

But if you want to find the subsets of your numbers its not a good idea that convert them to `int` ! you can use `combinations` to grub the subsets from tuple for example :

```
>>> from itertools import combinations 
>>> [list(combinations((1,2,3,4),i)) for i in range (1,5)]
[[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)], [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)], [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)], [(1, 2, 3, 4)]]
>>>
```

But if you just want to slice your numbers in 2 part you don't need convert to int, you can use the following list comprehension :

```
>>> [(i[:2],i[2:]) for i in [''.join(map(str,i)) for i in matrix]]
[('12', '34'), ('12', '43'), ('13', '24'), ('13', '42'), ('14', '23'), ('14', '32'), ('21', '34'), ('21', '43'), ('23', '14'), ('23', '41'), ('24', '13'), ('24', '31'), ('31', '24'), ('31', '42'), ('32', '14'), ('32', '41'), ('34', '12'), ('34', '21'), ('41', '23'), ('41', '32'), ('42', '13'), ('42', '31'), ('43', '12'), ('43', '21')]
```

In this case you need to convert your tuples with int element to str you can do it with `''.join(map(str,i)) for i in matrix` then you can join them.and use a slicing to get the desire parts.

Also if you want yo convert the parts to int use a `map` function :

```
>>> [map(int,(i[:2],i[2:])) for i in [''.join(map(str,i)) for i in matrix]]
[[12, 34], [12, 43], [13, 24], [13, 42], [14, 23], [14, 32], [21, 34], [21, 43], [23, 14], [23, 41], [24, 13], [24, 31], [31, 24], [31, 42], [32, 14], [32, 41], [34, 12], [34, 21], [41, 23], [41, 32], [42, 13], [42, 31], [43, 12], [43, 21]]
```

> The `reduce` function is apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable, from left to right, so as to reduce the iterable to a single value. For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5).

Comment: I convert my numbers to strings later in the script. This was just the first part I was having trouble with :)

Comment: @Chef1075 check out the edit . also i putted the link on answer

Comment: @Chef1075 is the result of `combinations` the desire subsets that you want ?

Comment: People usually downvote unclear questions, But this is indeed a good ans

Comment: @BhargavRao yep, i attempt to give a complete answer! thanks!

Comment: this only works for length four string digits, also I already provided and answer using map and creating pairs

Comment: @PadraicCunningham As the OP didn't say anything about another length i just gave this answer , and about yours , its good too but mine has different in slicing and its is in one line! also this is a Vague question! so i gave many answers :)

Comment: I think  `"''.join(map(str,i)) for i in matrix` is pretty similar to what I answered quite a while ago. Doing everything in one line is not the be all and end all especially when dealing with someone who is obviously not very experienced, the reduce code to a beginner may as well be double dutch.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i dont have any idea about your answer ! as this is a very simple task! but about beginner i'm agree so because of that i attempt to explain more and clearly!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 3), (1, 3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4, 2), (1, 4, 2, 3), (1, 4, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3, 4)]

print([int("".join(map(str,tup))) for tup in l])
[1234, 1243, 1324, 1342, 1423, 1432, 2134]
```

If you want to split into two parts:

```
out = []
for tup in l:
    joined = "".join(map(str, tup))
    half = len(joined) // 2
    a,b = int(joined[:half]),int(joined[half:])
    out.append((a,b))
print(out)
[(12, 34), (12, 43), (13, 24), (13, 42), (14, 23), (14, 32), (21, 34)]
```